# Libgdx/java Performance crash with box2d light

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, light

**Background Info**

Hey guys i am currently working on a little rpg :) and today i tried to implement some easy light ....

**Main Question**

When i use Point light in my Project the fps will get slower and slower ... i have got a very good pc, so it cant be my gpu or cpu ... So what did i miss?

Heres an Screenshot [image]

You can see in the left bottom corner the fps : 6.
By the way, i disabled vsync and my gpu is an gtx 960 ... so i dont really know why i have so low fps ...

Player class :

```
package Mobs;


public class Player {

AnimatedSprite animatedSprite;
SpriteBatch batch;

Light licht = new Light(Color.WHITE,500);


public int state = 0;
public int netState = 1;
float speed = 2f;
public Vector2 position = new Vector2(256,256);
public Vector2 networkPosition = new Vector2(0,0);



public Player(){



}


public void update(){

       state = 0;

       if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)){ 
           position.x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 100f;


           state = 1;
           //System.out.println(currentState);
       }
       if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)){
           position.x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 100f;    


           state = 2;
           //System.out.println(currentState);
       }
       if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)){ 
           position.y += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 100f;


           state = 3;
           //System.out.println(currentState);
       }
       if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)){ 
           position.y -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 100f;


           state = 4;
           //System.out.println(currentState);
       }



}

public void setX(float x){

    position.x = x;

}

public void setY(float y){

    position.y = y;

}

public void draw(float f, float g, OrthographicCamera camera){

    position.x = f;
    position.y = g;

    //System.out.println("In beforeSetState : "+currentState);
    animatedSprite.setState(state);
    //System.out.println("In after : "+currentState);
    animatedSprite.createAnimation();

    camera.position.set(f,g,0);
    camera.update();

    licht.drawLight(camera, f+25 , g+25);


    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(animatedSprite.convertAnimationTOframes(),f,g, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);   
    batch.end();



}


public void doSetup(){


    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite();


}



public float getX(){


    return position.x;


}

public float getY(){


    return position.y;


}


}
```

And my "Light" class :

```
package Screen;


public class Light {


World world;
RayHandler rayHandler;
PointLight pointLight;
Body player;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;



public Light(Color farbe, int radius) {

    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),false);
    rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);

    pointLight =  new PointLight(rayHandler, 500 , farbe , radius, 0, 0);
    pointLight.setSoftnessLength(0f);

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();


}


public void drawLight(OrthographicCamera playerCam, float x, float y){

    world.step(1 / 60f, 8, 3);


    debugRenderer.render(world, playerCam.combined);

    pointLight.setPosition(x,y);

    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(playerCam.combined);
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();




}

public void removeLights(){

    rayHandler.removeAll();
    pointLight.remove();


}


}
```

Because i still got laggs, heres my MainClass :

```
public class LauncherScreen implements Screen{

//-----------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------idle Animation----------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------

Map duengon;

AnimatedSprite animationForMultiplayer;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;   
Player mySelf;

OrthographicCamera mpPlayerCam;
OrthographicCamera camera;

static Client client = new Client();
Launcher launcher = new Launcher();


int[][] map = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}, 
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
               {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    launcher.update();

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //------------------------Draws the Map-----------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------


    duengon.ubdate(map, camera);



    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //------------------------Draws the Players-------------------------------
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------



    for(MPPlayer mpPlayer : launcher.getPlayersValue()){   

        animationForMultiplayer.setState(mpPlayer.state);

        animationForMultiplayer.createAnimation();          

        camera.position.set(mpPlayer.x,mpPlayer.y,0);


        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();                
        spriteBatch.draw(animationForMultiplayer.convertAnimationTOframes(), mpPlayer.x, mpPlayer.y,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);     // #6
        spriteBatch.end();

        System.out.println("mpPlayer : "+mpPlayer.x+" "+mpPlayer.y);


    }


    mySelf.update();
    mySelf.draw(launcher.getPlayerX(), launcher.getPlayerY(), camera);

    camera.update();

    System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());  

    System.out.println("player : "+launcher.getPlayerX()+" "+launcher.getPlayerY());



}




@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    animationForMultiplayer = new AnimatedSprite();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();              
    mySelf = new Player();

    mySelf.doSetup();

    mpPlayerCam = new OrthographicCamera(0,0);
    mpPlayerCam.setToOrtho(false);


    camera = new OrthographicCamera(0, 0);
    camera.setToOrtho(false);

    duengon = new Map();



}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    spriteBatch.dispose();
    mySelf.doDispose();
    animationForMultiplayer.doDispose();
    duengon.doDispose();


}






 }
```

The .doDispose() in my mainClass are methods which disposes the resource from the classes is use

Thanks for your help and your time :)

Comment: what does `player.createFixture(polygonFixture);` do?

Comment: It attach a box2d Dynamic Object to Player :) Thx for looking at my Code, it isnt often that i get an answer

Comment: No problem. Would you mind editing your post with that code included? FYI, I am running under the assumption that you are somehow continually creating resources with each draw cycle and not freeing them up. This would cause the rendering to slow down as it has to draw more and more. I am trying to locate where that might occur.

Comment: I could remove that Part, because it only "draws" an Dynamic Polygon at the Screen which is attached :) the problem is with the Light

Comment: Can you try removing that code temporarily and checking performance? Additionally, is there anywhere in your code that you see you are creating objects that can be rendered?

Comment: And Theres my Problem... I have got an  screen class, where i draw my game, But only a 10x10 big Tile map and my Player :/ nothing more, before i added the Light Into my Projekt i got about 300-400 konstant fps, and now with this Very simple Light only 30-60 with fps flucation. Just Tried my Project without the Bodydef and Polygon stuff, the Same fps as before :/

Comment: I haven't worked much with Box2D, but can you place limits on how far to draw the light geometry? It might be extending farther than needed and causing performance issues.

Comment: Allright :) But First i Need go to School, when im back i update my Code thanks man :D

Comment: I just tested something ... without ligth its lagging to :/ when i only draw the player i got about 100 fps thats much yeah, but every few seconds it drops  to 40-60 and i dont know why, maybe cause of the render method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not disposing anything, you might want to look into the dispose() function of LibGDX 
Here is the link
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html

if thats not the problem please let us know.

Comment: Ah, that's the answer to what I was thinking in the comments on the post. Good find on this

Comment: Did it, ubdated my code :) but still got laggs, like every 3-5 seconds :/ maybe its because of my render method ?